# How to mmap a struct as shared anonymous memory?

Tags: c, struct, mmap

I am trying to mmap a struct as anonymous shared memory so it can be shared across multiple child processes. However whenever I access the struct outside of the functions that create it, I get a segfault. The code is derived from trinity fuzzer, which can be found here https://github.com/kernelslacker/trinity .

first we have a excerpt of a header which declares and defines the struct we will be using. Note shm is declared as a global below the struct declaration.

```
struct shm_s {
struct childdata **children;

struct stats_s stats;

unsigned int running_childs;

/* rng related state */
unsigned int seed;

#ifdef ARCH_IS_BIARCH
/* Check that 32bit emulation is available. */
unsigned int syscalls32_succeeded;
unsigned int syscalls32_attempted;
#endif

/* pids */
pid_t mainpid;
pid_t last_reaped;

/* various flags. */
enum exit_reasons exit_reason;
bool dont_make_it_fail;
bool spawn_no_more;
bool ready;
bool postmortem_in_progress;

/* Use dispatch queue instead of locks. */

/* main<>watchdog serial queue, for reap_child()
 *  provides exclusion so they don't both try at the same time. */
dispatch_queue_t reaper_queue;

/* to protect from multiple child processes from
 * trying to disable the same syscall at the same time. */
dispatch_queue_t syscalltable_queue;

/* child<>child serial queue, used so only one child spews debug output */
dispatch_queue_t bugQueue;

/* global debug flag.
 * This is in the shm so we can do things like gdb to the main pid,
 * and have the children automatically take notice.
 * This can be useful if for some reason we don't want to gdb to the child.
 */
bool debug;

};

extern struct shm_s *shm;
```

In the c file we have the create and init functions for the struct.

```
struct shm_s *shm;

#define SHM_PROT_PAGES 30

void create_shm(void)
{
    void *p;
    void *redbefore, *redafter;
    unsigned int shm_pages;
    unsigned int wholesize;

    /* round up shm to nearest page size */
    shm_pages = ((sizeof(struct shm_s) + page_size - 1) & PAGE_MASK) / page_size;
    wholesize = (SHM_PROT_PAGES + shm_pages + SHM_PROT_PAGES) * page_size;

    /* Waste some address space to set up some "protection" near the SHM location. */
    p = alloc_shared(wholesize);

    redbefore = p;
    redafter = p + (SHM_PROT_PAGES + shm_pages) * page_size;

    /* set the redzones. */
    memset(redbefore, 0x77, SHM_PROT_PAGES * page_size);
    memset(redafter, 0x88, SHM_PROT_PAGES * page_size);

    /* set the redzones to PROT_NONE */
    mprotect(redbefore, SHM_PROT_PAGES * page_size, PROT_NONE);
    mprotect(redafter, SHM_PROT_PAGES * page_size, PROT_NONE);

    /* clear the whole shm. */
    shm = p + (SHM_PROT_PAGES * page_size);
    memset(shm, 0, shm_pages * page_size);
    printf("shm: redzone:%p. shmdata:%p. redzone:%p end:%p.\n",
       redbefore, shm, redafter, p + wholesize);
 }

void init_shm(void)
{
    unsigned int i;

    printf("shm is at %p\n", shm);

    shm->stats.total_syscalls_done = 1;

    shm->children = zmalloc(max_children * sizeof(struct childdata *));

    shm->bugQueue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    shm->reaper_queue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    shm->syscalltable_queue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

   for_each_child(i)
   {
       struct childdata *child;

       child = alloc_shared(sizeof(struct childdata));
       shm->children[i] = child;

       child->pid = EMPTY_PIDSLOT;

       child->logfile = NULL;
   }
}
```

Here is the alloc_shared function, that actually creates the shared memory.

```
void * alloc_shared(unsigned int size)
{
    void *ret;

    ret = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    if (ret == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("mmap %u failure\n", size);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* poison, to force users to set it to something sensible. */
    memset(ret, rand(), size);
    return ret;
}
```

Then finally the functions create_shm and init_shm are called like this in a separate file.

```
create_shm();

init_shm();
```

The program crashes whenever it gets to shm->stats.total_syscalls_done = 1; inside init_shm. I printed the address of shm and it's the same after its created in alloc_shared and in init_shm, so I don't think the pointer is being corrupted.
Either way I don't understand why I am unable to access the struct outside of create_shm().

Comment: What is the value of `page_size` before `create_shm()` ?  Make sure it is set to `getpagesize()` (`#include <unistd.h>`). I tested your code and apart from this problem I had no crash with `init_shm`.

Comment: `page_size` is set to `getpagesize()` before caling `create_shm()` . What operating system are you using? If it's Linux than I think that explains why it works for you and not me. I've tried this both on FreeBSD 10.1 and Mac OSX 10.10.1, but not Linux yet. I think this code might rely on undefined behavior from c's perspective but its actually well defined on Linux with gcc, so thats why it works on Linux. I'm going to compile it and run on Linux and test this theory.

Comment: Just some quick questions: 1) What is the output of the printf "shm: redzone: shmdata: redzone: end"? 2) If you put `shm->stats.total_syscalls_done = 1` at the end of `create_shm()`, does it still crash? 3) Does your program do anything between `create_shm()` and `init_shm()`? 4) Can you `printf("%p", &shm->stats.total_syscalls_done);` and see what that says?

Comment: The output is `shm: redzone:0x10a0ad000. shmdata:0x10a0cb000. redzone:0x10a0cb000 end:0x10a0e9000`, Putting `shm->stats.total_syscalls_done = 1` at the end still causes crashes. Basically the first thing to access a member of shm causes a crash. Nothing else happens between `create_shm()` and `init_shm`. The printf of `&shm->stats.total_syscalls_done` is 0x10a0cb008 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what the OP answered in the comments, the output of the printf was:

```
shm: redzone:0x10a0ad000. shmdata:0x10a0cb000. redzone:0x10a0cb000 end:0x10a0e9000
```

Notice that `shmdata` is at the same address as the redzone after (`redafter`), both being at `0x10a0cb000`.  This means that `shm_pages` was zero.

This line is most likely the problem:

```
shm_pages = ((sizeof(struct shm_s) + page_size - 1) & PAGE_MASK) / page_size;
```

I'm guessing that `PAGE_MASK` is `0xfff`.  If so, then that expression will always evalutate to 0.  As chmike points out, since you are dividing by page_size anyways, there is no need to use `PAGE_MASK` at all.  In that case, your code should read:

```
shm_pages = (sizeof(struct shm_s) + page_size - 1) / page_size;
```

Comment: This &PAGE_MASK is useless if we divide by page_size. The OP should check the value of PAGE_MASK.

Comment: Thanks, changing that line fixed the problem, but how come this runs on linux then?

Comment: @2trill2spill I'm not sure.  Either `PAGE_MASK` wasn't the same or maybe `mprotect()` had a different behavior.  If you are curious you should debug it on Linux to find out.

Comment: For my test I defined PAGE_MASK as page_size - 1, which is the bad value. I checked again and indeed `shm==redafter`. Apparently the mprotect doesn't prevent from reading !!!???!!?

Comment: @chmike Strange... Did you check the return value of `mprotect` to see if it returned some kind of error?  Maybe there is some reason it won't allow it?

Comment: I found the problem. I did have a segmentation fault caused by the protection. The problem is that my IDE (QtCreator 5.2.1) didn't show it when I ran the program. I had to execute the program in a shell to see the segmentation fault message. With the IDE, the program is silently terminating at the location of the segmentation fault.